# C# ESC POS Special characters

Tags: c#, printing

I'm making a class for ESC POS printing.

It needs to support special norwegian characters: ÆØÅæøå

The problem is that I can't just use them in a string.

"Data to print: ÆØÅæøå" will print as "Data to print: ??????"

According to the documentation these chars prints the special characters i need:

(char)91 prints "Æ"

(char)92 prints "Ø"

(char)93 prints "Å"

(char)123 prints "æ"

(char)124 prints "ø"

(char)125 prints "å"

**So my question is:** Is there any better way than to do a Replace for each of the characters?

Here is the code that connects to printer and sends data:

```
        Socket clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        clientSock.NoDelay = true;
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.11");
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ip, 9100);
        clientSock.Connect(remoteEP);
        byte[] byData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(buffer);
        clientSock.Send(byData);
        clientSock.Close();
```

**Solved:**

```
Encoding nordic = Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM865");
byte[] byData = nordic.GetBytes(buffer);
```

Comment: I struggled with this for days and was trying windows encoding 1252 also tried UTF8 but above mentioned solution worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is a standard codepage (like [code page 865 for Nordic languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_865)), you can use the appropriate encoding:

```
Encoding nordic = Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM865");
```

Check [supported encodings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) for the `Encoding` class to see if there is a match. But from the [character layout of 865](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_865#Code_page_layout), it looks like you will need to replace characters yourself.

You can create characters mappings using a dictionary, but obviously a large switch/case statement will do just fine for start (you can refactor it if ever get the need one day).

Comment: According to the ESC POS documentation this should work, but it says "865" is not a valid encoding.

Comment: It now works using: Encoding nordic = Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM865"); TYVM

Comment: @OMGKurtNilsen: Glad to hear that. Sorry, I missed the Name column in the [table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx#remarksToggle), I'll update the post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ASCII encoding is what you want -- see what happens when you use UTF-8.

Comment: ESC POS printers use ASCII commands. UTF8 doesn't mess up the commands, but doesn't fix the special character problem.

Comment: UTF-8 will send two octets for those characters... which I doubt will work. I would suggest Latin-1 (I seem to recall that .NET's ASCII does stick to 7 bit).

Comment: Doesn't seem like changing any encoding is going to work. I think ESC POS is using custom ASCII tables. Guess I just have to do a replace.